# Binding instances without class arg in Guice

Tags: java, generics, guice

Why doesn't this workin Guice?

```
binder().bind(instance.getClass()).toInstance(instance);
```

I don't quite understand which generics edge case this violates, it looks sound to me. The error message in IntelliJ is:

```
toInstance (capture<? extends java.lang.Object>) in LinkedBindingBuilder cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `instance.getClass()` is related to `instance`.

Say `instance` is a `Number`: `instance.getClass()` is a `Class<? extends Number>`, because `instance` might be an `Integer`.

And then the type inference algorithm doesn't know that `instance` is an instance of that `Class<? extends Number>`. By the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), `toInstance` is a consumer method, but because it's bounded by an `extends` bound, the only thing you can pass to it is literal `null`.

I can't think of a clean way to do this, without some warning suppression. But in this case it's fine to suppress (provided `instance` is an instance of a reifiable class): you know more than the compiler about the types, so go ahead and use the escape hatch.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! The compiler can't infer the return type of a dynamic method call.